# How to integrate Azure Edge Module to a Spring boot application

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-iot-sdk

I have a spring boot application that extracts data from a device with the specified intervals using spring scheduling.
Now I wanted to integrate the same spring boot application to push data using Gateway module.I am not able to find any integration point

Comment: Which container did you want to run the application in , windows container or linux container? Have you followed the sample and is it helpful for you?

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this [repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-samples) on GitHub. It contains samples on Java. The tutorial [Azure IoT Edge BLE Data Converter Module with Java](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-samples/tree/master/java/simulated_ble#azure-iot-edge-ble-data-converter-module-with-java) showcases how one might build a module for Azure IoT Edge in Java.